# NoTypeConversionAvailableException: camel rest dsl

Tags: rest, post, apache-camel, postman

I have a web service like this:

```
<camelContext id="camel-CallAPI" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" >
             <!--Web service starts working -->
           <restConfiguration bindingMode="auto" component="restlet" host="localhost" port="8889"/>
           <rest path="/check">
           <post uri="/version" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
           <to uri="direct:first"/>                
            </post> 
           </rest>     
           <route>         
          <from uri="direct:first"/>
              <setHeader headerName="Content-Type" id="header_contentType">
                  <constant>application/json</constant>
              </setHeader>
             <log message="after set header :: ${body}"/>
             <to uri="http4://..."/>
             <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>                  
             <log message="the result of the testCheckLastVersion :: ${body}"/>
```

I'm sending a json content to this web service with the help of postman, and I need my web service to send that json to another API that has been mentioned in direct:first.
but when I call my web service in postman an error is happening:

org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value: {version=apk.1.10.0} of type: java.util.LinkedHashMap on: Message[ID-localhost-localdomain-1549348033140-14-4]. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: java.util.LinkedHashMap to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value {version=apk.1.10.0}.

can any one help me with this?

Comment: Where in the Camel route do you see that exception, Camel logs that too. Also tell us what Camel version you use.

Comment: when I call the API ( <to uri="http4://..."/>) the exception is happening, and my camel version is 2.21

Comment: That is because you log the message body first and its streaming based, see this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html

Comment: I tried without any logs, but still have the same problem!

Comment: Please try to add the following attribute to your camelContext or to your route element `streamCache="true"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, the exception caused because I was set the bindingMode="auto" in camelContext which was not suitable here, by removing that, the problem solved.

```
<camelContext id="camel-CallAPI" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" >
             <!--Web service starts working -->
           <restConfiguration component="restlet" host="localhost" port="8889"/>
           <rest path="/say">
              <post uri="/hi" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
                <to uri="direct:first"/>
              </post> 
           </rest>         
           <route>         
              <from uri="direct:first"/>
                 <setHeader headerName="Content-Type" id="_setHeader2">
                     <constant>application/json</constant>
                 </setHeader>
           <to uri="http4://..."/>
           <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
           <log message="the result of the testCheckLastVersion :: ${body}"/>  
          </route> 

</camelContext>
```